# HTML5+JS vs. традиционные языки

Tags: javascript, java, c#, html5

Други, коллеги и проч. программерская нечисть :)

В последнее время становится все более и более модным новое направление в разработке, то что условно назовем html5+js. Вкратце выглядит это так - есть браузерная среда в которой ведется не только разработка юай, но также и собственно бизнес-логика. Особенно это заметно для мобильной разработки (десктоп пока вынесу за скобки). Взять тот же Tizen OS или почивший уже WebOS, поднимающий голову Chrome OS - все это тот самый html5+js

Плюсы в общем то понятны: пресловутый *write once - use everywhere*, низкий порог вхождения (похапистов то ведь много).

К сожалению мои личные познания в браузерной разработке достаточно небольшие, посему и вопрос: возможно есть в форуме двурукие коллеги, одинаково хорошо владеющие и браузерными разработками и традиционными способами.

Просьба поделиться своим опытом. Особливо меня интересует как устроена жизнь браузерного разработчика, в частности, с точки зрения доступа к ресурсам ОСи. Я понимаю как можно построить юай на html5+js, но чего не могу совершенно понять как же из браузера можно достучаться до сервисов, до нотификаций, да хотя бы до файловой системы?

**P.S.** Да это холивар :) - минусовать не буду. Все мнения welcome.

Comment: >поднимающий голову Chrome OS

что-то он поднимает-поднимает, да всё никак поднять не может

Comment: > как же из браузера можно достучаться до сервисов, до нотификаций, да хотя бы до файловой системы

серверными приложениями, на том-же js,  я думаю с php многие уйдут на ноду, как только спроса станет больше, т.к. не надо будет переключать в голове синтаксисы. 

Насчет бизнес логики в браузерах... всё зависит от степени доверия клиенту. т.е. если это покупатель в магазине, то логика на сервере, а если это админская панель, то в общем-то данным можно доверять, лишь бы авторизация совпадала.

Comment: вы кстати обратили внимание что js уже в qt поддерживается ? http://qt-project.org/wiki/JavaScript

Comment: @Barmaley, похапистов то ведь много, а быдлопайтонистов мало?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну разработчики допиливают свои методы в мобильное приложение и становится возможным юзать и файловую систему, и нотисы, и многое другое (прим [phonehap](https://github.com/lampaa/org.apache.cordova.startapp/blob/master/src/android/startApp.java))

Плюсов много - быстрота разработки, дешевизна. Минус тут один - тормоза. Сложно сделать более менее плавную! анимацию средней сложности. У меня например `fadeIn` картинки на полный экран вроде и нормально отрабатывает, но приложение задумывается на секунду.

Comment: Означает ли сие, что как только скорость станет достаточной - то все перейдут на html+css+js?

Comment: @Barmaley: Вполне возможно — перешли же все с чистого ассемблера на высокоуровневые языки как только процессоры стали позволять?

Comment: @Barmaley означает, что да. Технология позволяет сделать тоже самое, но быстрее и легче.

Comment: @VladD нет ты неправ, на высокоуровневые таки перешли из-за проблем с поддержкой ассемблера

Comment: @lampa покажи как создать бд и сделать простейший запрос к ней в выкидыванием результатов в html табличку

Comment: @Barmaley sqlite? В браузерах есть такая штука, как websql:

 var db = window.openDatabase("DBName", "1.0", "description", 5*1024*1024); //5MB

 db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM test", [], function(sql, data) {
   var tr = $('<tr>');
   
   for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
    $('<td>').html(result.rows.item(i)['label']).appendTo(tr);
   }
   
   $('table').append(tr);
  }, null)
 });

Не правда ли, красиво?:)

Comment: @lampa месье понимает толк в извращениях. (Это я про callback hell)

Comment: @alexlz по моему нормальный код. В купе с широкоформатным дисплеем вообще идеально))

Comment: @alexlz, 2 колбэка для Вас уже callback hell? @lampa, если использовать forEach вместо for будет еще красивее.

Comment: @Lucky А сколько колбэков будет callback hell?

Comment: @alexlz, это субъективное ощущение. Для меня думаю как минимум 5 вложенных колбэков.

Answer (score 4):

Хоть я сам плотно работаю с этими технологиями (html+JS+css), я не очень понимаю желание общественности видеть JS абсолютно везде. Мне кажется уже почти не осталось облостей, где не пробовали использовать JS: web-приложения, gamedev, SmartTV на телевизорах, микроконтроллеры, OS (как мобильные, так и мифическая ChromeOS). Мне конечно на руку такая популиризация JS, но вот в результате у меня телефон превращается в сковородку при попытке посмотреть небольшую демку на HTML5 Canvas, а простенькая демка на WebGL отжирает половину всей мощности ноута.

Comment: Ну это и неудивительно, работать через браузер это то же самое что и удаление гланд через ректальное отверствие - можно конечно, но удобнее все таки традиционным способом.

Comment: Отключите webgl в браузере. Зачем он вам тогда?

Comment: Я не жалуюсь на юзабельность, я утверждаю что есть ряд задач, которые лучше решать с помощью подходящих технологий. Я сам с удовольствием изучаю WebGl и делаю простенькие приложения на canvas, но желание воткнуть JS в создание мобильных приложений меня удивляет.

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас вас заминусуют люто, так как «истинные» программисты (это те кто пишет на крестах, ну или как минимум на яве) на дух не переносят когда html+css+js называют языками программирования. Ну а когда речь заходит о том что будущее за «универсальным» вебом который един везде, от ОпераМини до UltraHD телевизора, они вообще кипятком начинают писать, боясь что их низкоуровневые вставки на АСМе это прошлый век и более никому не нужны... и драйвера\ос\компиляторы\ уходят в прошлое

Comment: @Олег Б я вот тоже считаю что html+css+js на язык не и тянет, но вот и пытаюсь разобраться...

Comment: Html+css ещё ладно, ну а JS чем не язык? Виндоус стор позволяет интегрировать в себя Html5+js как полноценное приложение.

Comment: @Олег Б, да и кстати, минусует то меня истинный html5+js разработчик @pirj - так и не пойму за что

Comment: Как говорится, если есть спрос, то есть и предложение. Люди хотели писать программы для системы на html + js, им дали это.

Comment: Ему «печёт» от того что вы указали PHP но забыли про рельсы ;)

Comment: Проблема на мой взгляд в том, что сначала был веб, для которого придумали html+js (ну или наоборот - кому как нравится). Потом html+js начал покушаться на *святое* и решил, что браузер может являться полноценной средой - по сути браузер решил что он может стать осью - что и напоминает известную присказку *рожденный ползать летать не может*. В этом и есть проблема (на мой взгляд конечно)

Comment: Захожу в хром, нажимаю F11 (Fullscreen) и ищу какую нибудь демку на Unity3D для меня самого это удивительно.

Comment: Никак не пойму смысл холиваров. Необходимо выбирать платформу исходя из задач и имеющихся ресурсов.

Answer (score 1):

имхо, основное и реальное удобство - это разработка на десктопе. Т.е. открываем сафари или хром и тестим сколько влезет. оттестили, собрали приложение, поправили баги из-за небольших отличий движка на мобильных устройствах от десктопа, прикрутили фишки, зависящие от железа и все. **как бы**... затыков хватает, кроме прочего, в частности тормоза андроида и 3-го айфона (4-го айпода) не дают идее стать полноценной, а заказчики хотят обычно поддержать андроиды чуть ли не с api7 и айфоны с ios5 и ранее.
в остальном препятствий нет. есть еще альтернативы - mono, например.